# How to reliably delete message from gmail? [ActiveUp.Net.Mail]

Tags: c#, wpf, email, imap

I wrote a programm reading specific messages from gmail. After reading and analysing I want to delete them. However, I can't get it to work. I use the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes a set of E-Mails by their messageID from a given mailbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messageIds">The IDs of the messages to delete</param>
    /// <param name="mailBox">The mailbox to delete the messages from</param>
    public void DeletMails(List<int> messageIds, string mailBox)
    {
        if (messageIds.Count<1)
        {
            return;
        }
        // get the mailbox
        Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
        
        // create a collection of flags to set for the emails
        var flags = new FlagCollection();
        // set only the deleted flag
        flags.Add(new Flag("DELETED"));

        Logging.Log.Info($"Deleting {messageIds.Count} mails");
        // set the flag for each email in the messageIds
        try
        {
            foreach (var id in messageIds)
            {
                mails.DeleteMessage(id, true);
                mails.SetFlags(id, flags);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Log.Error($"{ex.Message}:{ex.StackTrace}");
        }

        Logging.Log.Info($"Finished deleting {messageIds.Count} mails");

        Client.Expunge();
        Client.Disconnect();
    }
```

I know there mey be some duplicates in the code

- mails.DeleteMessage(id, true);
- mails.SetFlags(id, flags);
- Client.Expunge();

However. It does not work.

When I log into my gmail account, I can still see the emails. Only change: they are marked as read and the label is removed from them. (Example: I label each email from service@paypal.de with the label PayPal using the filter settings of gmail, then I get all the emails from the mailbox PayPal and remember their ID and delete them. After that they are marked as read and they no longer have the label PayPal, but they are not deleted from the mailbox PayPal.)

There is no exception thrown when executing the code.

Any idea why? Do you recommend using another Mail-API? I am using ActiveUp.Net.Mail.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: For gmail, you need to move them to trash.  Deleting them removes the folders label, which effectively makes them “Archived”.

Comment: @Max Ah, ok. Thanks for your help. Would you put that as an answer so I can close the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.

@Max: The IMAP settings do (semi) work. However, it is a little bit annoying ;)
As mentioned [here](http://limilabs.com/blog/delete-email-permanently-in-gmail) you have to:

1. set 'When I mark a message in IMAP as deleted' to '**Expunge off – Wait for the client to update the server.**'
2. set 'When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder' to '**Immediately delete the message forever**'

But as described in the second setting you have to delete the message from all IMAP folders. Google seems to mix folders and labels. So labeling an e-mail with a filter in the gmail settings actually gives this email a secondary label/folder. The first is 'INBOX'. To remove it, so that it doesnt show up in the gmail app, you have to delete the message from INBOX and the other labeled folder with setting the DELETED flag for this message. But you have to do that for the INBOX and the other Folder, where the messages have different IDs.

Then the message is moved to the Gmail/Trash folder, where it is kept for 30 days or something like that before it is finally deleted.

Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

For GMail you need to move them trash (`UID MOVE x "[Gmail/Trash]"`).  Watch out for localization of the folder.

Gmail considers the \Deleted flag to be removing the label from that message, which means deleting the Inbox label is effectively the same as archiving the message.

Comment: sorry, had to redo the accecpt. Now the mails have the [Imap]/Trash label. Which means they still occur in the Inbox of the gmail android app, marked with that label instead. Deleting them removes the label and archiving them :( Any Idea of how tp remove them permanently without them showing up in the gmail app?

Comment: https://www.limilabs.com/blog/delete-email-permanently-in-gmail mentions gmail settings: “When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder:”

1 - Archive the message (default)
2 - Move the message to the Trash
3 - Immediately delete the message forever

however. setting it to "3" doesnt seem change the behaviour at all. Messages still show up in gmail app either with "trash" label or without any label :(

Comment: The IMAP settings dont work.  You need to move it to the trash, and if you really want it gone forever switch to trash then delete and expunge it from there